# Wait for an asynchronous function

Tags: sharepoint-online

I work on a script to recover information in a list and create a pdf with it.
To create my PDF I use makePDF and JSOM to recover the information.
I've already created my pdf and recover my data, but my function doesn't work with many list's items.

```
var id;
function pdfCtrl($scope){
$scope.form = { id:0};
var allItems;
var listeDef = new Array();

onQueryFailed = function(sender, args) {
    console.log('Request failed ' + args.get_message());
}

$scope.downloadPdf = function($event){
    var x = $scope.form;
    $event.preventDefault();
    var clientContext = SP.ClientContext.get_current();
    var web = clientContext.get_web();
    var list = web.get_lists().getByTitle("Congés");
    var query = SP.CamlQuery.createAllItemsQuery();
    allItems = list.getItems(query);
    clientContext.load(allItems);
    id = x.id;
    clientContext.executeQueryAsync(
        Function.createDelegate(this, onQuerySucceededDown2), 
        Function.createDelegate(this, onQueryFailed) 
        );      
};

onQuerySucceededDown = function(){
    var listEnumerator = allItems.getEnumerator();  
    while (listEnumerator.moveNext()){
        var currentItem = listEnumerator.get_current();
        if (currentItem.get_id() == id){
            pdfMake.createPdf(genratepdfDefinition(currentItem)).download('optionalName.pdf'); }
        //else if (id == 0){
            //pdfMake.createPdf(genratepdfDefinition(currentItem)).print();
            //pdfMake.createPdf(definition).download(); 
//      }
        else {

        }
    }
}
```

}

I search the problem and I found the function always use the same "current item".
So I want to wait for the end of the creation of my pdf and after that create the next.
If somebody can help me, I will love him!
Thanks!

Answer (score 0):

Check with the vendor of that pdfMake API.

You can achieve it if it has a Callback function or returns a Promise

Answer (score 0):

Put the `createPdf` functionality into a function, and call the function in the loop, passing the `currentItem`.  This way `currentItem` is scoped to the function, and will not update as the `currentItem` in the `onQuerySucceededDown` function gets updated.

```
function createPdf(item) {
    if (item.get_id() == id){
        pdfMake.createPdf(genratepdfDefinition(item)).download('optionalName.pdf'); }
    //else if (id == 0){
        //pdfMake.createPdf(genratepdfDefinition(item)).print();
        //pdfMake.createPdf(definition).download(); 
    //}
    else {

    }
}

var onQuerySucceededDown = function(){
    var listEnumerator = allItems.getEnumerator();  
    while (listEnumerator.moveNext()){
        createPdf(listEnumerator.get_current());
    }
}
```

To help understand variable scopes, try the following in Dev tools:

```
for (var i = 0; i < 5; i++) {
    setTimeout(function() {
        console.log(i);
    }, 1000);
}
// Should see 5 outputted five times

var test = function(i) {
    setTimeout(function() {
        console.log(i);
    }, 1000);
};
for(var i = 0; i < 5; i++) {
    test(i);
}
// Should see 0, 1, 2, 3, 4 outputted
```

Comment: this solution work when i want to create a pdf with the item's. But when i want to create all the with (value 0) the problem is the same..

Comment: I don't understand what you're trying to do.  Can you explain again?

Comment: I want to create many PDF thanks to a SharePoint list. But, with the asynchronus work, the create fucntion use always the same defintion.

Answer (score 0):

I resolve my problem thanks to this code :

```
function createPDF(item){  
    var def;
    var thisComptePromise = ++ comptePremise;
    if (item.get_id() == id){
        pdfMake.createPdf(genratepdfDefinition(item)).download('optionalName.pdf'); }
    else if (id == 0){
        var promiseGenerateDefinition = new Promise(
                function (resolve, reject){
                    console.log('on demarre le promise ' + thisComptePromise);
                    def = genratepdfDefinition(item);
            window.setTimeout(
                    function() {
                        // On tient la promesse !
                resolve(thisComptePromise);
            }, Math.random() * 2000 + 1000);
        });
        promiseGenerateDefinition.then(
                function(){
                   pdfMake.createPdf(def).download()
                   console.log('fin premise' + thisComptePromise); 
                }).catch(
               function(){
                   console.log('promesse rompue');
               }     
                );
    }
        //pdfMake.createPdf(genratepdfDefinition(item)).download();}
        else {
        }
    }
```